# Use the return() function and not have a newline

Tags: python, python-2.5

In my python program, there are functions within functions, and I've noticed that there are varying amounts of line between where the previous function ends and the first function starts.

Output:

```
end of previous function


start of first function
```

However, when the return() statement isn't used, "None" is printed at the end of the function.

Is there any way to get the program to only print out one line after the end of a function, or is this an unavoidable part of python?

(may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space), but you can't use this for return I don't think)

Example code:

```
def function1():
    ...stuff

def function2():
    function1()
    ....morestuff

while True:
    function2()
```

This will return 2 lines of "None". If return("") is added to the end of each function, just white space is there, and so are the new lines. Is there a way to have a certain amount of lines, or to get rid of them altogether?

ACTUAL CODE EXAMPLE:

```
def stop():
    print("stop")

def login():
    print("login")

def list():
    print("list")

def runscript():
    answer=raw_input("input")
    if answer == "stop":
        print(stop())
    elif answer == "login":
        print(login())
    elif answer == "list":
        print(list())

while True:
    print(runscript())
```

This returns "None" as well as the designated output. If a return("") is added to the end of each function, it still outputs different lines

Comment: `return()` is **not a function**. It is a statement.

Comment: What? You'll need to show more information. `None` is only printed if you actually print the result of the function. If you don't want to print anything, don't call print!

Comment: Your question is not clear, consider providing a short code example

Comment: And the *default return value* of a function is `None`. If you don't return anything different, `None` is returned instead. If you don't want `None` printed, *don't print the return value*.

Comment: I don't want the newline though. Is there any way to not have a new line?

Comment: There is no newline involved in anything you've shown.  Instead of confusing everyone, why not give a fully self-contained piece of code that we can copy and paste to see what the problem is?

Comment: @DSM added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `None` because of the print statements in runscript. Remove them:

```
def runscript():
    answer=raw_input("input")
    if answer == "stop":
        stop()
    elif answer == "login":
        login()
    elif answer == "list":
        list()
```

btw, you probably want to add a space after input: `raw_input("input ")`